# Cant run dlib module in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6, conda, dlib

I have installed dlib for my python 3.6 in my conda environment...but when i run a set of codes in my python idle ,it shows no module found for 'dlib'..What should I do?

Comment: Open the python repl and import dlib to see if you really install it successfully.

Comment: shows no module found

Comment: So, you did not install dlib successfully. Install again and pay attention if any error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest method to install dlib for Python in a conda environment. Note this will only install dlib for Python, you won't be able to use it for C++.

To install dlib for your conda environment, type this line in your terminal :

`conda install -n <nameofyourenvironment> -c conda-forge dlib`

Since the name of your env is given, you can type it without activating the conda environment.

The conda command-line interface will then tell you what changes will occur in the env. You have to accept them to install the module.

`Proceed ([y]/n)? Y`

Be careful, conda module installation uses a static approach when it comes to module version compatibility. Installing a new module require to downgrade other modules in order to ensure compatibility. Downgrading might remove functionnality of your downgraded modules.

Finally, to check the list of installed modules in your conda env, just type :

`conda list -n <nameofyourenvironment>`

Dlib should be there. If not, feel free to copy-paste here the error message you got when trying to install it.

Side note : you can find most available modules for conda here : https://anaconda.org/